# Sinch does not receive incoming call from Push notifications when the App was terminated

Tags: sinch

I have successfully integrated Sinch and everything works great except when the App is terminated. The first Call never gets registered by -[SINCallClient client:didReceiveIncomingCall:] or -[SINCallClient client:willReceiveIncomingCall:]

If I answer that call - the app opens - Sinch Client gets initiated but never recognises any incoming calls.

I have tried numerous ways and have isolated my SinchClient to be owned by the AppDelegate.

This issue can be reproduced by not initiating the SinchClient until Sinch Managed Push delegate receives the VOIP push notification.

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

Step 1: Don't initiate the sinch client on App Launch

Step 2: Setup your Sinch Push Delegate

Step 3: Initiate a call and receive the VOIP Push token

Step 4: Report to CallKit in accordance with Apples iOS13 guidelines

Step 5: Initiate your SinchClient

The Sinch Client gets initiated and never receives any incoming calls therefore making it impossible to connect that call.

Here is my SinchClient init

```
convenience init(_ id: String) {
        self.init()
        
        self.userId = id
        
        self.sinchClient = Sinch.client(withApplicationKey: "xxxxxxxx",
                                        applicationSecret: "xxxxxxxx",
                                        environmentHost: "clientapi.sinch.com",
                                        userId: self.userId)
        
        self.sinchClient.setSupportCalling(true)
        self.sinchClient.enableManagedPushNotifications()
        self.sinchClient.delegate = self
        self.sinchClient.start()
        self.sinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection()
    }
```

```
 func clientDidStart(_ client: SINClient!) {
        print("SINCH CLIENT DID START")
        self.sinchClient.call().delegate = self
        
    }
```

This is my log when receiving my first call while Sinch Client is not started. The Sinch client gets initiated immediately after reporting to CallKit, I can't start it before since that would cause the app to crash.

```
Sinch Managed Push! Received
New Sinch Client Init
(adm_helpers.cc:57): Failed to set stereo playout mode.
(adm_helpers.cc:77): Failed to set stereo recording mode.
(audio_device_generic.cc:17): BuiltInAECIsAvailable: Not supported on this platform
(audio_device_generic.cc:27): BuiltInAGCIsAvailable: Not supported on this platform
(audio_device_generic.cc:37): BuiltInNSIsAvailable: Not supported on this platform
2020-07-02 16:01:31.820653+1000 Josari[1370:334218] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2020-07-02 16:01:31.820814+1000 Josari[1370:334218] Metal API Validation Enabled
SINCH CLIENT DID START
```

Comment: Please look at the sample app in the downloads. 
One thing I see right away is   self.sinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection() you should not start that when using push.

Comment: thanks cjensen, it doesn't make a difference in my case since I just take whatever gateway is faster. If the the push comes before listening fires than I handle it and vise versa.

I could propably disable listening but thats not an issue right now